# Passing props to child components in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Having a bit of trouble passing props down from a parent component to a child component with es6.

```js
// Parent component
const Carousel = () => (
  <nav className="projects-nav">
    <div className="projects-nav__wrapper">
      <CarouselItem
        title="Mowat"
        client="Jon Mowat"
        image="/images/mowat.jpg"
        icon="images/icons/video.svg"
        url="/mowat.html"
      />
    </div>
  </nav>
);

// Child component
const CarouselItem = () => (
  <div className="project project--mowat">
    <Letter />
    <Title />
    <Description />
  </div>
);

// Child component where prop is inserted
const Title = ({ title }) => (
  <a href="/mowat.html" className="project__title">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
  </a>
);
```

Do I need to pass the prop from the Carousel to the CarouselItem then to the Title component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

With React 16.2 and before, you have to explicitly pass props down the component tree to reach a component descendant.

```
const CarouselItem = ({ title }) => (
  <div className="project project--mowat">
    <Letter />
    <Title title={title} />
    {/*    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pass prop to grandchild */}
    <Description />
  </div>
);
```

Starting from React 16.3, you can use the [ContextApi](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/replacing-redux-with-the-new-react-context-api-8f5d01a00e8c) to skip this and inject state to designate components and circumvent the actual component tree.

This functionality is also available with libraries like [Redux](http://redux.js.org) or [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org) which take advantage of the *unofficial* [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (not the same as the one coming out in 16.3).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the most straight-forward way would be to pass the prop through `CarouselItem` as you say.

```
const CarouselItem = (props) =>
    <div className="project project--mowat">
        <Letter />
        <Title title={props.title} />
        <Description />
    </div>
```

However, doing this multiple levels deep can get a little unwieldy, and has even gotten the name "prop drilling". To solve that, a new context API is being added in React 16.3, which allows passing data down through multiple levels. [Here's a good blog post about that.](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b)

Answer (score 1):

use spread operator `{...props}`

```
const CarouselItem = (props) => (
  <div className="project project--mowat">
    <Letter />
    <Title {...props}/>
    <Description />
  </div>
);
```

CarouselItem is parent and Title is child recieving all props from parent

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily pass all the props `CarouselItem` has to its `Title` child. There's no need for a `Title` component to be aware of certain props that other components require (e.g. `Letter` and `Description`).

Comment: If props are more than 3 then it makes sense, similar to how we avoid passing more than three  arguments to function and use objects. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-params

Comment: I agree, in that case we should pass the props in a simpler way. However, would only extract the necessary props (e.g. `const titleProps = { prop1, prop2, prop3, ... }` ) and spread them (`<Title {...titleProps} />`).

Comment: Yes that makes sense